# Red-Black Tree - Black Height restriction

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, tree

I was reading wiki about [Red-Black Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree).

Can someone elaborate on the 5th restriction:

> 1. A node is either red or black.
> 2. The root is black.
> 3. All leaves (NIL) are black. (All leaves are same color as the root.)
> 4. Both children of every red node are black.
> 5. Every simple path from a given node to any of its descendant leaves contains the same number of black nodes.

I'm having difficulties understanding it since given the state of the example RBT after [the final case of *insertion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree#Operations) (case 5 on wiki) gives us:

[image: Wiki Red Black tree]

Doesn't 4 and 5 have one more black node than 1,2, and 3?

Comment: No, because 1, 2, and 3 are black nodes, where 4 and 5 aren't, so all five of those paths has two black nodes.

Comment: @IanMcMahon 

How come 4 and 5 aren't black? Aren't they supposed to be, due to restriction 3?

Comment: certainly seems that way, doesn't it.  Now you've got me wondering if perhaps the wiki is wrong.  Can the wiki be wrong?  That shakes my faith in the solidity of the world!

Comment: yeah the Wiki is wrong `U` should have been red from the beginning. Therefor also red in the end.

Comment: The Wikipedia article's pictures are misleading w.r.t. property 5 and coloring.

Comment: Ok, it makes more sense if the illustration is wrong. So if the U was red in the beginning, it wouldn't get to case 5 since case 3 handles it. I need to find another rotation example then. Wiki betrayed me.

Comment: Yeah, actually, ignoring the colors the `tree` before the rotation and after it got the exactly same structure only mirrored, so it would make no seance to rotate it...

Comment: "In many of the presentations of tree data structures, it is possible for a node to have only one child, and leaf nodes contain data. It is possible to present red–black trees in this paradigm, but it changes several of the properties and complicates the algorithms. For this reason, this article uses "null leaves", which contain no data and merely serve to indicate where the tree ends, as shown above. These nodes are often omitted in drawings, resulting in a tree that seems to contradict the above principles, but in fact does not."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 are all subtrees.  We know the colour of the root node in trees 1, 2 and 3 to be black.  We do not know whether any of the nodes 1-5 are leaf nodes, because this case of insertion may have been called recursively on some N that was the grandparent of the newly inserted node (from insertion case 3).

Before and after the rotation, subtrees 1, 2 and 3 are all below one black node (G before, P after), and subtrees 4 and 5 are below two black nodes (G and U before, P and U after).  Subtrees 1, 2 and 3 each have one more black node than subtrees 4 and 5.

Comment: Looking more into it, I will go with this.

1,2,3,4, and 5 aren't leaves per se, but subtrees of their own. N and G have black children (heads of 1,2,3), so every path that comes up from there doesn't really change, since it was the same number of black nodes up that way as before. Every path that passed through U before had U and G as black nodes (two), so after the rotation every path now had to pass through U and P black nodes (two). Which is the same number of black nodes as before. So the restriction still holds, assuming that the restriction held on the subtrees below them.

Comment: Additionally, subtrees 1,2, and 3 have one more black node in them than 4 and 5 because 4 and 5 passes through U to get the additional black node they need to match 1,2, and 3.

I kind of get it now.

Answer (score 1):

I just read it deeply, and it seems there was a problem with the picture.

Since `N` is the node which just been insert it means that before the last `insert` under `P` there were the children [1,3] or [2,3] (and the insert was of 2 or 1 respectfully). So in that case before the last insert `P` and `U` must have been red (and 4,5 are black).

Comment: No. The diagram does double-duty. It caters for two situations
(i) N is the node just inserted, in which case 1 & 2 don't exist
(ii) The node inserted is far below in one of sub-trees 1 or 2, N is original Node's grandfather or grandfather of grandfather etc and now the new Node that needs fixing up. The situation for (ii) will loop heading for the root, as long as current parent and current uncle are red, and the parent of the grandfather is also red.

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations to James for deciphering the Wiki diagram!  It's not wrong, just ambiguous.

The page's "talk" tab mentions that "The triangles are not meant to represent leaves but subtrees. Some subtrees have black circles at the top to indicate that their root must be black."

Apparently, triangles lacking circles represent subtrees (including leaves) for which the root node's color, and tree depth, are unknown (and presumably irrelevant).

So the diagrams simply don't provide sufficient information to tell whether or not "rule 5" is violated.  We have to take it as a given that it's not.

Answer (score 0):

The NIL node configuration is completely optional. The only reason that they are black is because you want to save extra red nodes by default. They can be later turned red as needed.

The allocated black node increases the black height, which is also an optional height difference. Because you have to record the NIL flag somewhere, you can allocate it as a black node.

You can save only 1bit address space; usually the system is very close to its limit.